# Generate all commutators and anti-commutators up to a certain order of a list of matrices

Tags: matrix, function-construction, code-request, broken-code

I am given a list of matrices. At first order I want to evaluate the commutators and anti-commutators of all pairs in the list and return a new list that contains two lists: one containing all commutators and one with the anti-commutators. In order 2, one first constructs 4 lists: one that creates the pairs (using `Tuples` for instance) of elements from the commutator list of the previous order, one for the anti-commutators and the two lists containing pairs from both of lists. Symbolically, $\{\{A,A\},\{A,C\},\{C,A\},\{C,C\}\}$, where $A$ is the list of anti-commutators and $C$ the list of commutators from the previous step. Notation $\{A,B\}$ denotes the list with all ordered pairs with first element from list $A$ and second from list $B$. After obtaining the four lists of tuples, one then evaluates the commutators and anti-commutators for each list of tuples, resulting in a lists of 8 lists of matrices. One may proceed and repeat the process, up to some order $n$.

I have tried the following but I have no good grasp of what I am actually doing with the functions I am using, so this was after trial and error. The functions I have defined work correctly for orders 1 and 2 but fall apart after that, so something does not generalise properly.

```
com[M_] := M[[1]] . M[[2]] - M[[2]] . M[[1]]
com[A_, B_] := A . B - B . A
acom[M_] := M[[1]] . M[[2]] + M[[2]] . M[[1]]
acom[A_, B_] := A . B + B . A
tst = {A, B};

generateComsAcomsIter[set_] := Module[{},
  Return[{set, {Map[acom, (Tuples /@ Flatten[Tuples[
          DeleteCases[set, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Infinity], {2, 1}], {{1, 
           3}}]), {2, 2}], 
     Map[com, (Tuples /@ 
        Flatten[Tuples[
          DeleteCases[set, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Infinity], {2, 1}], {{1, 
           3}}]), {2, 2}]}}]
  ]

generateComsAcoms[set_, order_ : 1] := 
  Module[{rcoms, racoms, FOComsAcoms},
   
   racoms = 
    DeleteCases[(Apply[acom, #] & /@ Tuples[set, {2}]), {{0, 0}, {0, 
       0}}];
   rcoms = 
    DeleteCases[(Apply[com, #] & /@ Tuples[set, {2}]), {{0, 0}, {0, 
       0}}];
   FOComsAcoms = {racoms, rcoms};
   If[order == 1, Return[FOComsAcoms], 
    Return[Nest[generateComsAcomsIter, FOComsAcoms, order - 1]]]
   ];
```

This returns the following for order 1 (I didn't add order 2 as it is long).

```
generateComsAcoms[tst, 1]

{{2 A . A, A . B + B . A, A . B + B . A, 2 B . B}, {0, A . B - B . A, -A . B + B . A, 0}}
```

Note that in practice I will run this with the list `tst` consisting of $2\times2$ (or $n\times n$ in general) matrices, so the could should correctly for such cases.

Comment: Do you really need the results to be segmented into this specially structured lists, or do you just need to enumerate all possible commutators and anticommutators? For example, is this okay for you? `With[{order = 1}, Groupings[Tuples[{a, b}, order + 1], {comm -> 2, anticomm -> 2}]]`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I do need to know where the terms are coming from. So I need to know for example the terms that come from the anti-commutators of previous commutators etc.

Comment: I am wondering though if there is a way to reshape the result from your answer in order to get the list of lists that I am looking for... If that's not hard to do then it would be quite elegant solution.. It should also generalise correctly to order $n$. If I run your code with ```order>1```, I get elements that are commutators of $a$ or $b$ with their commutators or anti-commutators, and these terms should not exist. I want the commutators and anti-commutators of the tuples of the result from the previous order.

Answer (score 1):

For an example we that a list of matrices m1,m2 (but it could be any number of matrices):

```
list= {m1,m2};
```

To get all possible commutators and anticommutators with matrices from the list, we use "Outer" and rearrange the answer using "Transpose" and "Flatten". As capitalized variable names are used for the system, I use c and a for the commutator and anticommutator lists:

```
{c, a} =  Flatten /@ Transpose[
Outer[{#1 . #2 + #2 . #1, #1 . #2 - #2 . #1} &, list, list,1],
{3, 2,1}]

{{2 m1 . m1, m1 . m2 + m2 . m1, m1 . m2 + m2 . m1, 
  2 m2 . m2}, {0, -m1 . m2 + m2 . m1, m1 . m2 - m2 . m1, 0}}
```

For the second step, we define a helper function "pairs" that gets all tuples:

```
pairs[l1_, l2_] := Tuples[{l1, l2}]
order2 = {pairs[a, a], pairs[a, c], pairs[c, a], pairs[c, c]}
```

[image]

And for numerical matrices:

```
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}];
{c, a} = 
 Flatten /@ 
  Transpose[
   Outer[{#1 . #2 + #2 . #1, #1 . #2 - #2 . #1} &, list, list, 1], {3,
     2, 1}]

{{-0.0941443, -0.0161421, 0.0120272, -0.120298, -1.2253, 
  0.810861, -0.610004, 0.102877, -1.2253, 0.810861, -0.610004, 
  0.102877, 0.388385, 1.83253, -0.178276, 0.431455}, {0., 0., 0., 
  0., -0.437255, 1.07776, 0.0945714, 0.437255, 
  0.437255, -1.07776, -0.0945714, -0.437255, 0., 0., 0., 0.}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is nice but how does this generalise beyond second order?

Comment: I need a function that depends on some order variable that will generate the commutators and anti-commutators of all terms from the previous order. So, in your answer, in order 2 you have generated the tuples but not the commutators and anticommutators. Also, if I run your code with ```list``` being a list of matrices, the code returns errors and an incorrect result.

Comment: I added an example for numerical matrices.  The level specifications were missing. I do not understand order 2. You have 4 list: aa,ac,ca,cc. What exactly are you the doing with thouse? Can one concatenate the 4 list into one and then proceed like order 1?

Comment: No because I need to keep track of all the different contributions for the specific problem I am solving. So from the second step, after taking the commutators and anti-commutators of aa, ac, ca, cc we should get a list of 8 lists.

Comment: Should it not be 16 lists? {aa,aa},{aa,ac},{aa,ca},{aa,cc},{ac,aa},{ac,ac},{ac,ca},{ac,cc},{ca,aa}..

Comment: It should be 8. aa are all tuples from a, ac from a and c etc. To each of the four aa, ac, ca and cc we apply the commutator and anti-commutator, thus generating 8 lists in total.